# How do I update the timezone on a travelling Windows laptop?

Tags: windows-7, time-zone

I want to automatically update the timezone on my Windows 7 laptop after traveling to a new locale.

Is there any method of doing this, perhaps by using an Internet location service?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [GeoSense for Windows](http://www.geosenseforwindows.com/) which claims to be able to provide a semi-accurate geo-location device for your computer.  This will require some kind of internet connection (WiFi preferred) to be able to get your location.

I would hope that once Windows 7 has a vague idea of where you are, by using this service, then it will update your timezone accordingly.  But I cannot say for sure that it will.

Also see [Windows Sensor and Location Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463473)

If you look in your Control Panel you will see a "Location and Other Sensors" panel.

About Location Sensors:

> By using sensors, programs on your computer can customize information and services for you based on your computer's current location, surroundings, and more. For example, with a location sensor and your computer, you may be able to find a nearby restaurant, get directions to that restaurant, send the directions to a friend, and then follow the directions on a map as you travel to your destination.

A-HA!

[Coding 4 Fun Timezone Changer](http://c4ftimezone.codeplex.com/) - will require the GeoSense platform unless your have another sensor installed.

> This is an extension for my MEF Utility Runner to change your system time zone based on your current location. Uses Windows 7 location feature.
>
> It subscribes to location change events (new to Windows 7) to be aware of current location. When the location changes it determines the base UTC offset from a web service, then searches the system for time zones with that same offset.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

We use TimeTraveller (http://www.godotandco.com) - it's a small utility that finds your location from your network connection and automatically updates the time zone in your laptop when travelling.